# perl -le inside parens doesn't working in bash script

Tags: bash, perl

I'm using a script to run a content from a text file with a perl command. It is inside parentheses and is showing command not found. I tried to include this line to a variable and execute by $() or ${variable} but the return is always "(: command not found"

```
#!/bin/bash
...
( perl -le 'print "test"' && cat example.txt) > example2.txt || ( rm -rf example2.txt && false )
```

Comment: For one thing, you're missing the closing single quote at the end of your perl one-liner. But it's not really clear what you're trying to do with that command. Can you please explain in more detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted does not exhibit the behaviour you claim.

```
$ cat a.bash
#!/bin/bash
( perl -le 'print "test" && cat example.txt) > example2.txt || ( rm -rf example2.txt && false )

$ ./a.bash
./a.bash: line 2: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
./a.bash: line 3: syntax error: unexpected end of file

$
```

After adding the missing `'`:

```
$ cat a.bash
#!/bin/bash
( perl -le 'print "test"' && cat example.txt) > example2.txt || ( rm -rf example2.txt && false )

$ ./a.bash

$
```

Comment: If you edit your question, let me know and I'll delete this answer.

Comment: I think the problem was related to the lack of single quote. Thanks.